# XSLT: Match all elements of a namespace except one element

Tags: xslt

I want to write an XSLT template that matches all elements of one namespace except one element. For example I want to match all elements `foo:*`, but not `foo:bar`.

Is that possible to define this in a selector or do I have to write an `xsl:if` condition within the `xsl:template` (and how can I test the local name of the element)?

Comment: XSLT matches elements (and other nodes), not tags. An element generally has two tags, a start tag and an end tag. It helps everyone communicate if you try to get the terminology right.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To do this, you can just have a template that matches **foo:bar** that does nothing with it like so:

```
<xsl:template match="foo:bar" />
```

To match other **foo** elements, you can use a more general template

The XSLT processor should match the more specific template first, and so **foo:bar** will be ignored, and all other **foo** elements matched by the other template.

So, for example, given this input XML

```
<foo:root xmlns:foo="foo.com">
   <foo:bar>No match</foo:bar>
   <foo:pie>Match</foo:pie>
</foo:root>
```

When you apply the following XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:foo="foo.com">
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

   <xsl:template match="foo:bar" />

   <xsl:template match="foo:*">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

If you wanted to do different processing on **foo:bar**, just add code to the relevant template.

The following is output, without any sign of **foo:bar**

```
<foo:root xmlns:foo="foo.com">
   <foo:pie>Match</foo:pie>
</foo:root>
```

Answer (score 6):

**XSLT 1.0:**

```
<xsl:template match="foo:*[not(local-name()='bar')]">
  <!--do stuff-->
</xsl:template>
```

**XSLT 2.0:**

```
<xsl:template match="foo:*[. except self::foo:bar]">
  <!--do stuff-->
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: @_Mads Hnasen: Your proposed XSLT 2.0 solution is wrong -- please, correct.

Comment: Thanks @Dimitre Novatchev, I've added the `self::` axis to the match expression.

Comment: +1, your XSLT 2.0 solution was the solution to my problem too! ^^ (My problem: refer to every possible template, except the one stated in the select).